# Does nativescript use 2 view models

Tags: nativescript

In the image of this project which is the view model file? I would have thought main-page.js but then main-view-model.js is titled "-view-model".

[image: tnsViewModel]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"view-model file" is not really a set programming concept. But I guess you mean a file which only holds one function which acts as a view-model. If that's the case, then `main-view-model.js` is most probably the "view-model file". Looking at the content it looks view-model-ish.

However 1, you need to look at main-page.js to see how that is used.

However 2, in NativeScript, view models are often [observable objects](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/data/observable/HOW-TO.html) and looking at this code, the `ViewModelItem` is *not* an observable object.

Answer (score 0):

not sure about that ViewModelItem object, but in NativeScript, view1.xml is the view and view1.js would be the "code-behind" and that means you will code the logic directly related to the view itself: Button has a `tap="getName"`? that function goes to view1.js...

viewModel files would be where you create observables with the datas you fetch from a remote source for exemple, and all the methods say '`saveName(ppl)`' that would POST your object to the server would be in the viewModel file...

you would create your observable like this:

```
var studentList = new StudentListViewModel([]);
var pageData = observableModule.fromObject({
    studentList: studentList,
    student: "",
    prof: "Choisir"
});
```

and any changes has to be set like that:

```
pageData.set("prof", prof)
```

hope it is clear...